# Difference between elements and subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there an example for $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} \subset 2^{\Omega}$, where $\mathcal{A} \bigcap \mathcal{B}$ is not equal to $\{A \bigcap B: A \in \mathcal{A}, B \in \mathcal{B}\}$?

I am thinking of letting $\Omega = \{1,2,\{2,3\}\}$, letting $\mathcal{A} = \{1,2\}$, letting $\mathcal{B} = \{1,\{2,3\}\}.$

Would it then be correct to say that $\mathcal{A} \bigcap \mathcal{B} = \{1\}$ whereas $\{A \bigcap B: A \in \mathcal{A}, B \in \mathcal{B}\} = \{1,2\}$?

Comment: in general $A\cap B:=\{x\in A: x\in B\}$ what is not the same that $\{x \cap y: x \in A, y \in B\}$

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I'm trying to show here, except the non-script As and Bs are what you have as xs and ys. Does the example make sense?

Comment: elements and subsets are *completely* different.  $\mathcal A \cap \mathcal B$ almost *never* equals $\{A\cap B|A\in \mathcal A; B\in \mathcal B\}$.  I think it'd be a pretty hard problem to come up with a case where they *do*.  If $\mathcal A = \{\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{3,4,5\}\}$ and $\mathcal B=\{\{3,4,5\},\{4,5,6\}\}$ then $\mathcal A\cap \mathcal B= \{\{3,4,5\}\}$.  But $\{A\cap B\} =\{\emptyset, \{3\},\{3,4\},\{3,4,5\},\{4\},\{4,5\}\}$.  Those are *completely different!

Comment: The $1 \cap \{2,3\} = \emptyset$ so you must include $\emptyset$ in your example.  And $2 \cap \{2,3\} =\emptyset$ as well, I think

Comment: I am assuming $1 = \{\emptyset\}$ and $2 = \{\emptyset, 1\} = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$?

Comment: Let  the collections of subsets be disjoint.  For example, {{1,2}} and {{2,3}}

Answer (score 1):

In your example with $\ \Omega =\{1,2,\{2,3\}\}\ $, neither $\ \mathcal{A}\ $ nor $\ \mathcal{B}\ $ are subsets of $\ 2^\Omega\ $. In fact, *none* of their elements are elements of $\ 2^\Omega\ $, which is the set
$$
\left\{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{\{2,3\}\} ,\{1,2\},\{1,\{2,3\}\},\{2,\{2,3\}\},\Omega\right\}\ .
$$
Noting that a singleton set $\ \{A\}\ 
$ should rarely, if ever, be conflated with its only element $\ A\ $, then $\ 1\not\in 2^\Omega\ $, $\ 2\not\in2^\Omega\ $, and $\ \{2,3\}\not\in2^\Omega\ $.

In general, two typical subsets $\ \mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}\ $ of a power set $\ 2^\Omega\ $ will *not* have the property that $\ \mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}=
\left\{A\cap B\,\left\vert A\in\mathcal{A}, B\in\mathcal{B}\right.\,\right\} $. If $\ \mathcal A=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\} \subset 2^{\{1,2,3,4\}}\ $ and $\ \mathcal B=\{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\} \subset 2^{\{1,2,3,4\}}\ $, for instance, then $\ \mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}=\emptyset\ $, but $\ \left\{A\cap B\,\left\vert A\in\mathcal{A}, B\in\mathcal{B}\right.\,\right\}=\left\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}, \{4\}\right\} $.

The sets $\ \mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}\ $ and $\
\left\{A\cap B\,\left\vert A\in\mathcal{A}, B\in\mathcal{B}\right.\,\right\} $ will be equal if and only if every intersection of one member of $\ \mathcal A\ $ and one member of $\ \mathcal B\ $ is also a member of both $\ \mathcal A\ $ and $\ \mathcal B\ $. For a simple example where this is the case, take $\ \mathcal A=\left\{C, C\cap D\right\} $ and $\ \mathcal B=\left\{D, C\cap D\right\}\ $, where $\ C\ $ and $\ D\ $ are different subsets of $\ \Omega\ $. Here, $\ \mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}=\{C\cap D\}=
\left\{A\cap B\,\left\vert A\in\mathcal{A}, B\in\mathcal{B}\right.\,\right\}\ $.